# Paste Google Docs URLs into Google Sheets and automatically get title and word count

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-docs

Probably a long shot, but does anyone know of any formulae or scripts that could be used with Google Sheets so that when you paste in a selection of URLs to Google sheets, it would automatically get the title and word count for each URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe could, *a priori*, be implemented using **custom functions**. It would query the Docs API for the desired metadata and return it into the cell.

This, however, is not possible since access to apis such as `DocumentApp` is not allowed from custom functions [(1)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts). Upon attempting to do so, they will return an error such as the following:

> You do not have permission to call DocumentApp.openByUrl.
>
> Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents (line 88).

#### Alternative

1. Insert the `=GETDOCWORDCOUNT()` and `=GETDOCTITLE()` functions as you please throughout your Sheets document. At first, they will show `#ERROR!` as result of the function, for the reason explained above:

   [image: Example sheet]
2. The code, when opening the Sheets document, creates a "Custom scripts" menu. After having placed your formulas in the document, click on the menu and select the `Run GETDOCWORDCOUNT` or `Run GETDOCTITLE` as you wish. The formulas in the Sheet that were previously shown as `#ERROR!` will be replaced by the result of running the functions. At this step, any error found whilst executing the `GETDOCWORDCOUNT`, `GETDOCTITLE` functions will also be shown to the user:

   [image: Example execution]

#### Code

```js
var GETDOCWORDCOUNT_FUNCTION_REGEX = /=GETDOCWORDCOUNT\((.+)\)/;
var GETDOCTITLE_FUNCTION_REGEX = /=GETDOCTITLE\((.+)\)/;
var A1_CELL_REGEX = /^[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*$/;

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu("Custom scripts")
    .addItem("Run GETDOCWORDCOUNT", "runGetDocWordCount")
    .addItem("Run GETDOCTITLE", "runGetDocTitle")
    .addToUi();
}

function runGetDocWordCount() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var finder = sh.createTextFinder("\=GETDOCWORDCOUNT\(.+)")
                 .matchCase(true)
                 .matchEntireCell(true)
                 .useRegularExpression(true)
                 .matchFormulaText(true);

  var results = finder.findAll();
  var errors = [];

  for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
    var range = results[i];
    var formula = range.getFormula();

    var cell = formula.match(GETDOCWORDCOUNT_FUNCTION_REGEX)[1];
    var url = sh.getRange(cell).getValue();
    try {
      range.setValue(GETDOCWORDCOUNT(url));
    } catch(e) {
      errors.push(range.getA1Notation() + ': ' + e.toString());
    }
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var title = errors.length.toString() + ' errors found';
    var prompt = errors.join('\n');
    ui.alert(errors.length + ' errors found', prompt, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

function runGetDocTitle() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var finder = sh.createTextFinder("\=GETDOCTITLE\(.+)")
                 .matchCase(true)
                 .matchEntireCell(true)
                 .useRegularExpression(true)
                 .matchFormulaText(true);

  var results = finder.findAll();
  var errors = [];

  for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
    var range = results[i];
    var formula = range.getFormula();

    var cell = formula.match(GETDOCTITLE_FUNCTION_REGEX)[1];
    var url = sh.getRange(cell).getValue();
    try {
      range.setValue(GETDOCTITLE(url));
    } catch(e) {
      errors.push(range.getA1Notation() + ': ' + e.toString());
    }
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var title = errors.length.toString() + ' errors found';
    var prompt = errors.join('\n');
    ui.alert(errors.length + ' errors found', prompt, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}

function GETDOCWORDCOUNT(url) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(url);
  var text = doc.getBody().getText();
  var words = text.split(/\S+/).length;
  return words;
}

function GETDOCTITLE(url) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(url);
  return doc.getName();
}

function isA1Cell(val) {
  if (typeof val != "string") return false;

  return A1_CELL_REGEX.test(val);
}
```

#### Demo

See a short video demo of the script [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AXv9.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, that's looking like it's going to get me closer to what I want to do. Ideally I'd like to paste a URL into any cell and run a different function on that cell and it convert the URL into the title or word count. So the URL wouldn't necessarily have to be in the A1 position. Or does the output of the function need to be in a diferent cell from the input URL?

Comment: Hey @Tyssen thanks for your comment. When I use `A1` in the code I am not referring to the `A1` cell in the Spreadsheet, but rather, to the [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation). The script can run in any cell of your choice. I have added a short video demo of the script on my post so that you can see how my script functions. Cheers

Comment: Ah OK. I wasn't put the cell the URL was in into the function. I've done that and it now appears to be working. Just a question on the word count though: for the article I tested, the function returned a value of 1113, whereas doing Tools / Word Count in the Doc itself returned 1131. I then tested the same doc using a few different online word counters and got 1112, 1167 and 1149. Do you know if there's any way to get closer to the word count that Google itself returns?

Comment: Thanks, I got all this working. I was wondering is there any way to have the formulas not destroy themselves when the script runs, maybe by inserting the value into a different cell? It would be nice to get updated word counts from time to time without having to re-paste the formulas into the cells.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function getIdTitleCount(url) {
  var id=url.slice(url.indexOf('/d/')+3,url.indexOf('/edit'));
  var title=DriveApp.getFileById(id).getName();
  var count=DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody().getText().split(/\s/).length;//This probably could be a better regex but by my count it works pretty well for simple text.
  Logger.log(id);
  Logger.log(title);
  Logger.log(count)
}
```

Comment: I've run it in my sheet and got an error `You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById…` Looking at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services it seems to be able to use services other than the ones listed, I have to use a custom menu, but I don't understand how to do that in my situation.

Comment: So I gather you’re trying to use it as a cell function and there are restrictions on what kind of services are available for cell functions. It might be possible for you to use the onedit trigger I’ll work up an example for you as soon as I get on my desktop

Comment: What ranges are you trying to paste into and would you prefer using a button or the on edit trigger?