# Get wordcount automatically in google sheets from google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-docs

I have used the code from an earlier post, see link below:

[Paste Google Docs URLs into Google Sheets and automatically get title and word count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557202/paste-google-docs-urls-into-google-sheets-and-automatically-get-title-and-word-c)

I am doing, to the best of my knowledge, the same thing as described in the post in the link above but I can't get the script to work. It still shows the same error message:

> Exception: You do not have permission to call DocumentApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents (rad 82).

What am I missing? According to the previous post it should work if you use a custom menu call instead of a custom function.
Thanks in advance!
/K

Comment: I just tried that script and it works fine for me. Probably you're doing something wrong. You need to describe your workflow more closely. Perhaps the simplest way is just to share your spreadsheet. Did you allow all required permissions to the script when you run the Custorm scripts first time? https://i.imgur.com/R7eJDBp.png https://i.imgur.com/RSxPmLE.png

Comment: And actually the script that grabs urls from column A, and put titles and numbers into columns B and C can be significantly shorter and simpler. Probably it makes little sense to mock 'custom functions' as soon they don't work as proper 'custom functions' anyway.

Comment: I got an alert about permissions and to the best of my knowledge, I have allowed all required permissions.

Comment: How do I share my spreadsheet here? do I add a link to it? I'm a beginner, so it can be something very simple I'm missing :)

Comment: One thing I thought of was that I added url to google docs for documents where I'm not the author. However, I have permission to edit the documents. I tried the script on google docs where I'm the author and it still didn't work for me. What am I missing?

Comment: *How do I share my spreadsheet here?* https://i.imgur.com/vIB7wMs.png copy and paste the link in your question

Comment: Here is the link to the google sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AVshE-zJr-CQFK9sqKki41wrrya9V451ipOkrI98QhI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type the function names in UPPERCASE. Exactly like they are in the script:

```
function GETDOCWORDCOUNT(url)
```

```
function GETDOCTITLE(url)
```

Here is workflow for `GETDOCTITLE()`
[image]

It will show the error again.

Keep calm and click on `Custom script` > `Run GETDOCTITLE`

[image]

And here we go:

[image]

Comment: Now it works! Thank you! However, as another poster in the post I got the code from pointed out, the wordcount script and the wordcount in google docs doesn't get the same number of words. What can I do to get the same wordcount?

Comment: Obviously there are different ways to count words. The script splits all text by "spaces" (tabs and "enters" included). So if you have two spaces in a row you will get one more "word" `''` for your counter. Etc. The word "word" has a pretty vague meaning, actually. If you manage to figure out which exactly chunks of text Google Doc consider as words you can try to reproduce its counter in your script. Until that you should consoled by the approximate calculations. I recommend you to mark this answer as accepted and post the next question about the best algorithm of word counting if you need it